# Was "Yellowstone" inspired by "Snowy River: The McGregor Saga"?

Tags: reference, yellowstone

*Yellowstone* (USA, 2018–) and *Snowy River: The McGregor Saga* (Australia, 1994–1996) have a lot in common, including:

- A large cattle and horse ranch, located in a beautiful mountainous area, is very much the reason for existence for the central family.
- The landowner is widowed.
- He holds a high elected position in state government.
- He has two sons and a daughter.
- One child's fear was responsible for the death of the mother.
- One son is likely to inherit the ranch for the next generation.
- One son has followed a very different profession.
- The daughter is smart, capable of almost anything, and determined not to let her sex get in the way.
- One of the male family members is adopted.
- There are conflicts with an adjoining large property, with continual dirty tricks used against the landowner.
- Aboriginal people often play crucial roles in the plot.
- One of the family is played by actor Josh Lucas.

Was *Yellowstone* inspired by the earlier (much inferior) work?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josh_Lucas At least one cast member was involved with both shows. Small world.

Comment: @Valorum, yes, that was already in my list. ¶ I wonder why the 3 down-votes. Is this type of question inappropriate for this site?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that it looks like you've cherry-picked elements that make them look similar. You could do much the same for any two shows that are based in the same location.